# How do I redirect my azure VM DNS to my registered domain?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine, cname

I recently purchased a domain from google and configured my Name Servers from Azure DNS Zones. I also got a new SSL certificate and set that up on my Azure VM such that my registered domain could run under https. This is all working fine however the original Azure VM DNS now says it's not secure.
Ex. purchased domain = https://www.example.com
Azure VM DNS = http://abc.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com

How can I redirect my users that are using the Azure VM DNS to my newly purchased domain and avoid this "Not Secure" message?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create TLS/SSL binding

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings

Answer (score 0):

From I got from the question you're using a VM instead of App Service, right?

Within your application, it needs to force the user to use **HTTPS** instead of *HTTP*. Just return HTTP status code 301 and the https url.